# Why 12.31.2013 last month is 12.01.2013?

Tags: javascript, date

Set the date:

```
var a = new Date('2013.12.31');
```

Output:

```
Tue Dec 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)
```

Modify date:

```
a.setMonth(a.getMonth()-1);
```

Modified output:

```
Sun Dec 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)
```

Comment: I suppose because you've not changed the day from `31` to `30`, and there are only `30` days in November, so Nov 31 === Dec 1.

Answer (score 7):

30 days has September, April, June, and **November**.  Subtracting 1 from the month portion of Dec 31 gives you Nov 31.  Since Nov only has 30 days, the extra day puts it into December.

Comment: @pickypg: Most? I see only 3 deprecation notices on [MDN Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Are there more? It doesn't give a notice for `get/setMonth`

Comment: Woops, I for some reason read this as `Java`. Ignore my comment

Comment: So, what shall I do to get the last day of last month? How about a.setDate(0);

Comment: @EcoChan Calculate the first day of the next month and subtract a day.